# How to enable and disable a link?

Tags: jquery

I have kind of a content slider which works like:

```
$('.boxes:not(:first)').hide();
    $(".links a:first").addClass("selected"); 
    $(".links a").click(function() {
        var activeLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
        $(".links a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $(activeLink).fadeIn();
    });
```

As you click on a box, it show next box and set next box link also active (which is good!):

```
$('.boxes').click(function(){
    var $activeBox = $(this);
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $activeBox.next().show();
    var $activelink = $(".selected");
    $activelink.removeClass("selected");
    $activelink.next().addClass("selected");
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to disable all the links for once(box1,box2,box3,box4,box5) except first one so that user can see the next box only clicking box1.

My question: How can I disable all the links except first one and enable the next box link as on the box is clicked?

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/13mg30Lf/3/

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/13mg30Lf/5/

```
$(".links a:not(:first)").attr("disabled","disabled");

$('.boxes:not(:first)').hide();
    $(".links a:first").addClass("selected"); 
    $(".links a").click(function() {

        if ($(this).attr("disabled") != "disabled"){
        var activeLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
        $(".links a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        $('.boxes').hide();
        $(activeLink).fadeIn();
        }

    });

$('.boxes').click(function(){

    var $activeBox = $(this);
    $('.boxes').hide();
    $activeBox.next().show();
    var $activelink = $(".selected");
    $activelink.removeClass("selected");
    $activelink.next().addClass("selected");
    $activelink.removeAttr("disabled");       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For disable a link with jQuery :

```
$('#box1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

That will prevent the default behaviour of a hyperlink, which is to visit the specified href.

If you want to disable specific link, just add a condition in this function, for example disable all element with class "disabled"

Answer (score 0):

Something a little cleaner, IMO: http://jsfiddle.net/13mg30Lf/12/

HTML

```
<div class="links">
   <a href="#box1" class="disabled" data-index="1">Box1</a> >
   <a href="#box2" data-index="2">Box2</a> >
   <a href="#box3" class="disabled" data-index="3">Box3</a> >
   <a href="#box4" class="disabled" data-index="4">Box4</a> >
   <a href="#box5" class="disabled" data-index="5">Box5</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <div id="box1" class="boxes" data-index="1">BOX 1</div>
   <div id="box2" class="boxes hide" data-index="2">BOX 2</div>
   <div id="box3" class="boxes hide" data-index="3">BOX 3</div>
   <div id="box4" class="boxes hide" data-index="4">BOX 4</div>
   <div id="box5" class="boxes hide" data-index="5">BOX 5</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function ShowBox(index) {
    if ($('.boxes[data-index="' + index + '"]').length) { // If a next box exists
        $('.boxes').addClass('hide'); // Hide all boxes
        $('.boxes[data-index="' + index + '"]').removeClass('hide'); // Show the next box
        $('.links a').addClass('disabled'); // Hide all links
        $('.links a[data-index="' + index + '"]').next('a').removeClass('disabled'); // Show the current link
    }
}

$('.links a, .boxes').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) { // If we don't have a disabled class
        if ($(this).hasClass('boxes')) { // If we're clicking the box
            ShowBox(parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'))+1); // Use next index            
        } else { // Else (clicking link)
            ShowBox($(this).attr('data-index')); // Use current index
        }
    }
});
```